# CSS transitions shaking in chrome and IE

Tags: html, css

I am new to developing, can anyone please help me with this.. css transitions are shaking in chrome and IE, I have tried all possible styling to correct it, but could'nt. please help!.

here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Khan_Z/qoL4xqhq/

```
<header>
  <h2 id="head1"><span>Sometimes </span><span>you win </span> <span>sometimes</span> <span>you learn</span></h2>
     <div>
        <h2 id="head2" class="subtitle fancy"><span>Hi</span></h2>
        <h2 id="head3" >ABCD</h2>
        <p id="head4">UVWXYZ:)</p>

     </div>
```

```css
#head1{
 width:100%;
 margin-top:375px ;
 font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
}
#head2{
 
 position:absolute;
 font-size:42px;
 
 margin-top:450px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:47%;
 
}
#head3{

 position:absolute;
 margin-top:460px;
 margin-left:43%;
 font-size:40px;
 
 line-height:2;
 text-align:center;
}
#head4{
 
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:510px;
 margin-left:40%;
 font-size:35px;
 
 text-align:center;
}
#head1{
 
 -webkit-animation: none;
 -moz-animation: none;
 -ms-animation:none;
     animation: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #CCCCCC;
}

#head1 span {
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 color: black;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #CCCCCC;
}
#head1 span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
 
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
#head1 span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
 
 animation-delay: 2s;
}
#head1 span:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 
 animation-delay: 3s;
}

#head2 {
 
 
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 color:black;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #CCCCCC;
}
#head2 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay:5s;
 animation-delay: 5s;
 
}
#head3 {
 
 
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 color: black;
 
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #CCCCCC;
}
#head3 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay:5s;
 animation-delay: 5s;
 
}
#head4{
 
 
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 0s backwards;
 color: black;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #CCCCCC;
}
#head4 {
 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
 -ms-animation-delay:6s;
 animation-delay: 6s;

}

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
      -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
     transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:  scale(1);
     transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
     -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:scale(2);
      transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
       -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:scale(5);
  transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:  scale(0) ;

 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-0deg);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of margin-top use top and use % instead of px on top it will be fine